Laplace Transform for Integral Equations
I have been asked to solve the integral equation $y(x)=1-\int_0^{x}(x-t)y(t)dt$.

I used the convolution theorem, that $F(p)G(p) = \int_0^{x}f(x-t)g(t)dt$.
For the integral in the problem, $\int_0^{x}(x-t)y(t)dt$, I said that using the convolution theorem we have $\int_0^{x}(x-t)y(t)dt = \frac{1}{p^2}L[y(x)] = \frac{1}{p^2}Y(p)$ (using the notation that $L[y(x)] = Y(p)$).
Rewriting the original problem replacing the integral with the expression found above, we now have:
$$y(x)=1-\frac{1}{p^2}Y(p)$$
From here, I am unsure where to proceed. I tried rearranging the equation so that the $Y(p)$ term is isolated, so that we have $(y(x) - 1)(-p^2)=Y(p)$, but was unsure how to take the inverse Laplace transform of $y(x)$ on the LHS.
$$L^{-1}[(y(x) -1)(-p^2)]=y(x)$$
Have I made a mistake in my approach?

I think your first mistake is you misstated the convolution theorem which should be $$f(t) \ast g(t)=\int\limits_0^t f(t-\tau), g(\tau) , d\tau=\mathcal{L}^{-1}F(s)\cdot G(s).$$

You need to take the Laplace transform of both sides of $$\int\limits_0^x (x-t), y(t) , dt=1-y(x)$$ assuming the Laplace transform $Y(s)=\mathcal{L}y(t)$, solve for $Y(s)$, and then take the inverse Laplace transform $y(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}Y(s)$ to determine $y(t)$.

@StevenClark Thank you, I looked again and I did misstate the theorem.

I believe this is doable without the convolution theorem as well as the Laplace transform: differentiating both sides with respect to $x$ we have $y'(x) = \int_{0}^{x} y(t) dt$, which can be differentiated again with respect to $x$ to obtain the equation $y''(x) = y(x)$.

Integral equation to be solved with Laplace transform
$$y(x)=1-\int_0^{x}(x-t)y(t)dt$$
Laplace transform of equation
$$Y(p)=\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{p^2}\cdot Y(p) \implies Y(p)=\frac{p}{p^2+1}$$
Apply inverse Laplace transform
$$y(x)=\mathcal{L}_p^{-1}[Y(p)](x)=\mathcal{L}_p^{-1}[\frac{p}{p^2+1}](x)=\cos(x)$$
